# Error using c DLL. Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#

I try use a dll created in c in c#, but I get the error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I see very topics here, but i'm not solve the problem. It's possible help me?

My C# code is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]

public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadRes", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

private static extern SRes LoadRes([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string str, bool type);
```

---

```
SRes sres = new SRes();
string path="C:\\123456.fil";
System.IntPtr load = LoadLibrary("lib.dll");
System.IntPtr adress = GetProcAddress(load, "LoadRes");            
sres = LoadRes(path, true);
```

My code to export in c is

```
__declspec(dllexport) SRes  LoadRes( const char *filename, bool header_only );
```

Thank's for help!!

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing something bad in your DLL? Not allocating memory, pointer problems, etc.?

Comment: I have an old dll and I have the same problem. The old dll was working in c.

Comment: try providing administrative rights to your application/library or whatever you are building.

Comment: What is SRes? Can you add the declaration for that one as well?

Comment: Note that you do not need LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress, using pinvoke does that automatically, you only need to declare LoadRes ...

Comment: I try with administrative rights and have the same error.

Comment: SRes is a class. How I can use PInvoke?